# "Добрый пес, но слишком лохматый." "Добрый пес" - какое это предложение?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Взяли собаку из приюта. Добрый пес, но слишком лохматый.

Возможно ли здесь трактовать предложение "Добрый пес" как назывное? По моему мнению, здесь возможна двоякая трактовка: с одной стороны, "Добрый пес" может рассматриваться как неполное предложение (подлежащее ясно из контекста, а "добрый пес" - сказуемое), с другой стороны, предложение можно считать двусоставным, но с инверсией (если имеется акцент на прилагательном). А можно ли считать это предложение назывным? Если да, то почему.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существуют **назывные предложения,** которые обозначают **эффект присутствия** наблюдателя в какой-либо ситуации (то, что он видит перед собой), например:

**Вокруг ни души. Какие-то постройки, сараи,  лохматый пёс возле будки**.

Заданное предложение **двусоставное**, там дается оценка собаки по внешнему виду и характеру.

(1) Пес дОбрый, но слишком лохмАтый. (2) ДОбрый пес, но слишком лохмАтый (при наличии инверсии ударение смещается на первое слово).

Пёс – подлежащее, добрый, но лохматый – сказуемое.

Comment: Спасибо. Можно ли рассмотреть "добрый пес" как неполное предложение? Например, рассмотрим такой случай: "Был недавно в Москве. Красивый город, но суетливый." Можно ли здесь, как и в примере о собаке, считать предложение неполным? Или эти примеры отличаются?

Comment: Нет, это обычное двусоставное предложение, аналогичное первому примеру. Там нет пропущенных членов предложения, подлежащее и сказуемое на месте. То, что Москва во втором предложении названа городом, это обычное построение текста, когда  названный предмет мыслится уже как известный и заменяется другим словом, чтобы избежать повтора.

Answer (score 3):

Предложение *Добрый пес, но слишком лохматый* в данном вами контексте двусоставное, то есть быть назывным уже не может. *Пес* — подлежащее, *добрый, лохматый* — однородные сказуемые. С чего вы взяли, что *добрый пес* может быть подлежащим? Даже в предложении *Наша собака — добрый пес* сказуемым будет только *пес*, а *добрый* — неизбежно определение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можно ли рассмотреть "добрый пес" как неполное предложение? Например, рассмотрим такой случай: "Был недавно в Москве. Красивый город, но суетливый." Можно ли здесь, как и в примере о собаке, считать предложение неполным?

Comment: @SergG нет, только в редком контексте можно представить, что там есть какой-то нулевой элемент, но в простом случае — точно нет. Это так называемые номинативные предложения, они по определению односоставны, то есть могут вмещать только один главный член, например: _Зима. Мороз. Добрый пёс._ В примере про город оба предложения двусоставные, во втором случае _красивый, суетливый_ — сказуемые.